# Why does my function get back "Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Tags: javascript

I've tried to find why the error occurs, and the helper functions work perfectly fine. But still i couldn't find the solution. Could you point out where exactly my function is broken, or breaks down?

**The goal is to return a number that is the smallest in its row, and greatest in its column.**

**Here's my code:**

```
function luckyNumbers(matrix) {
  for (let i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
          let ele = matrix[i][j];
          if (minInRow(ele) === maxInColumn(ele)) {
             return ele;
          }
      }
  }
};

matrix = [[ 5,  9, 21],
          [ 9, 19,  6],
          [12, 14, 15]]

console.log(luckyNumbers(matrix)); // expected output - [12]

matrix = [[ 5, 10,  8,  6],
          [10,  2,  7,  9],
          [21, 15, 19, 10]]

console.log(luckyNumbers(matrix)); // expected output - [10]





// --------------------- MIN_IN_ROW FUNCTION ---------------------------
function minInRow(arr) {
    let minNum = arr[0][0];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      
      for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
          let ele = arr[i][j];
          
          if (ele < minNum) {
              minNum = ele;
          }
      }
  }
  return minNum;
};

/* console.log(minInRow([[6, 5, 11],
                      [8, 7, 3 ], 
                      [9, 12, 1]])); */




// --------------- MAX_IN_COLUMN FUNCTION ---------------------------

function maxInColumn(arr) {
    let maxNum = arr[0][0];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        
        for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            let ele = arr[i][j];
            
            if (ele > maxNum) {
                maxNum = ele;
            }
        }
    }
    return maxNum;
};

/* console.log(maxInColumn([[3,  5, 6],
                         [2, 20, 30],
                         [9, 10, 2]])); */
// -----------------------------------------------------------------
```

**The output i get is:**

```
let minNum = arr[0][0];
                       ^
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at minInRow (/tmp/uEg6djEUrs.js:30:24)
    at luckyNumbers (/tmp/uEg6djEUrs.js:5:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/uEg6djEUrs.js:16:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
```

Comment: What is `arr` at the moment of the error? It's undefined and you need to find out why.

Comment: @mykaf i know that i need to find out. That's the reason why i asked it here man :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example `let ele = matrix[i][j];` returns a number, but you are trying to call ele[0][0] on this number inside `minInRow`, which is not an array.

A simple way of getting the min and max number of an array in JavaScript is with the Math.min and Math.max methods.

```js
var matrix1 = [
  [ 5,  9, 21],
  [ 9, 19,  6],
  [12, 14, 15]
];

var matrix2 = [
  [ 5, 10,  8,  6],
  [10,  2,  7,  9],
  [21, 15, 19, 10]
];

function luckyNumbers(matrix) {
  var minArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    var matrixRow = matrix[i];
    var min = Math.min(...matrixRow); // returns the minimum number of the row
    minArray.push(min); // add the minimum to the minimums array
  }
  return Math.max(...minArray);  // returns the maximum number of all the minimums
};

console.log(luckyNumbers(matrix1));
console.log(luckyNumbers(matrix2));
```

Answer (score -1):

You just have to remove [i] from the line 2 of luckyNumbers.

```
 function luckyNumbers(matrix) {
  for (let i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) { // you made additional lookup for the length
          let ele = matrix[i][j];
          if (minInRow(ele) === maxInColumn(ele)) {
             return ele;
          }
      }
  }
};
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. Explain the solution so the OP can learn

Comment: It still doesn't work

Comment: Then we have to check these functions `minInRow, maxInColumn` can you post those?

Comment: @PADMANABANGOKULA i already have, look at the code box

Comment: @PADMANABANGOKULA Hm, this doesn't make sense. It _should_ be `matrix[i].length`, no? Otherwise you get the "number of `i`s" and not the "number of `j`s".

Comment: Instead, the problem is that a number is passed to `minInRow` but in there an array access `[0][0]` is done.